# c++ shorthand operator-> operator()

Tags: c++, shorthand

Suppose I have:

```
Foo foo;
```

is there a shorthand for this?

```
foo.operator->().operator()(1, 2);
```

Comment: ::face palm:: **No.** ::shakes head in baffled disbelief::

Comment: I edited your question. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Who deleted my question about the second operator name and why? As far as I see there's no definitive information from the OP on that issue. What we currently have is just a guess from Potatocorn.

Comment: @Potatocom: yep, I made a typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you actually *meant* `foo.operator->().operator()(1, 2)`, and that you have control over the class `Foo`, a simpler form would be `(*foo)(1, 2)`. It requires the `operator*` to that defined though, but since we usually expect `foo->bar` to be equivalent to `(*foo).bar`, it seems reasonable.

If your `Foo` is a smart pointer class of some sort, which points to an object which defines an `operator()`, this would be the most concise way of calling the object's `operator()`.

But without more detail (and without you providing an expression that's actually valid C++ -- there's no way in which `operator(1, 2)` as you wrote it can be valid), it's impossible to answer your question. I'm just guessing at what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

Well... Yes. The *shorter* form would look as

```
foo.operator->()(1, 2)
```

As for eliminating the `operator ->` part... From the information you supplied so far it is impossible to say, but if it is implemented the way I can guess it is implemented (judging from your expression), then you can't eliminate it.

In C++ the use of overloaded `->` operator in an expression is interpreted as a chain of repetitive overloaded `->` calls, which eventually ends in a built-in `->` invocation. This means that at some point the overloaded `->` must return a pointer. Your overloaded `->` obviously doesn't return a pointer. So, in order to use it you have no other choice but to spell it out explicitly as `operator ->()`.

Comment: +1 for correctly specifying exactly what's needed to use `operator->`. I didn't realize that a compliant program could use non-pointer `operator->`, but it's possible!

Answer (score 0):

Well, no, but, assuming you have write permissions to the class, you could define another member function that calls operator(), and then you'd have something like:

```
foo->myfunc(1,2);
```

That you find yourself in this position is a sign that you (or the person who wrote this class) is being a bit too cute with operator overloading.

Comment: Err... No. It won't work. The OP's overloaded `->` returns a non-pointer. This immediately means that any attempts to call it as `foo->...` are ill-formed. It simply won't compile. (There's a chance for it to work if the overloaded `->` returns something that in turn has its own overloaded `->`, but it would be a stretch to make such a guess without any extra info.)

Comment: I see that -- f.operator->().myFunc(1,2) works.

Which I guess underscores the point that this seems to be a poor use of operator overloading.